# Problems creating android virtual device on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, android-virtual-device

I am currently trying to create an AVD in order to run an app emulator on eclipse. However, when I follow the steps necessary to create the AVD, eclipse is unable to create it. The SDK manager appears to have installed all of the necessary packages, so I don't think it's that. Is there a problem with the eclipse installation itself or did the ADT plugin not install correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Once I experienced some problems with AVD manager because I had installed ADK into a directory whose path that contained spaces (into Program Files, to be precise). What is the path to your ADK?